# Is there a simple way to search for google drive files given a file resource dictionary in python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I see how to use files.list with the q parameter to find files. I have a case where I have a file resource such as found here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource

However, my file resrouce (python dictionary) doesn't have a fileid, just other descriptors like title, description, mimetype, etc. I want to find any files that match the parameters of my file. the q accepts a querystring in a different format from a dictionary. Is there some function/utility that can convert my dictionary to an appropriate querystring? Otherwise I find myself checking which parameters are present and manually building a querystring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that you have to create the q parameter manually. Sorry. I think this would be a very useful library though if you write it.